# Why do we have to set responseType when using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I implemented a HTML which upload a file, and then download another file from server.
When handling the "download part", i noticed that if i download a binary file, i have to set `responseType` to `blob` or the file will be broken.

What confused me is that, HTTP header contains `content-type` which could tell `XMLHttpRequest` what type of file the server is sending. Why i have to set it manually? I don't understand the logic because it's server's turn to tell what the file type is, rather than predicted by client

```
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob'

.......

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
          if (this.status == 200) {

          var blob = new Blob([this.response]); // if i don't set responseType, this.response will be broken
          let a = document.createElement("a");
```

Answer (score 1):

*Your question made me realise I'm not entirely sure of the following, but it is how I have always looked at it.*

`responseType` sets the type of `xhr.response` so you can *process* it as a `Blob`; it lets you *retrieve* the results of the `xhr` request as a `Blob`. If you don't set it, `xhr.response` will be Text.

A server may have sent the data the right way based on a mime type, but it still only sends a stream of bytes with a mime type; the *interpretation* of the received bytes lies on your end, and the *received* data won't automatically be of the type `Blob` based on the mime type.

`Blob` is not a file type on the server; the server may know and send the mime types of files, but `Blob` isn't one of them, and `xhr.response` won't be a `Blob` just because the mime type suggests that a `Blob` would be the right type.

Also, you may want to process the `xhr.response` differently from what can be inferred from the mime type, and in that sense, it is a kind of override (though not with the same functionality as `xhr.overrideMimeType()`).

Comment: but some mine type is definitely `"blob"`, such as `application`. And as far as i know, `responseType` can be deduced from `mime-Type`. If you don't think so, please help to raise an example?

Comment: Yes, but, say, jpg files aren't sent as "blob", in fact, that mime type is rarely used and not directly related to responseType. responseType *could* be deduced from mime type, but it isn't, not by the xhr mechanism, as far as I know.

Comment: I still don't understand. .jpg is also a binary file, which is definitely `blob`, am i wrong?

Comment: JPGs are sent with mime type image/jpeg. xhr.response doesn't automatically become of the type blob just because the mime type is image/jpeg. You have to indicate with xhr.responseType that you want to process xhr.response as a blob.

Comment: But you still don't answer my question. I know "xhr doesn't automatically set responseType to `blob` because of `image/jpeg`. My question is, why? it should be `blob`, and can be a default value, unless user change it deliberately.

Comment: That "why" can only be deduced from the design considerations of the authors of the language. Maybe they felt it was up to the programmer to decide how to process the return independent of the mime type. Maybe they felt there are too many mime types, and the set of mime types changes too frequently, to implement and maintain a translation table in the language itself.